# Badly placed ()'s while declaring a function in tcsh

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to declare a function in tcsh and to call it.

```
#! /bin/tcsh -f

helloWorld () {
    echo "a"
}

helloWorld
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
< 512 mews2895 ~/tmp/script> 1.sh
Badly placed ()'s.
```

Does anyone here what the problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: `#! /bin/tcsh -f` should not have an space after `!`. Also, tcsh has no functions: http://www.tcsh.org/TipsAndTricks

Comment: @fedorqui: Actually the space is optional.

Comment: @KeithThompson oh, interesting and good to know. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 8):

tcsh does not support functions.

Best solution: Use a shell that does, such as bash.

If you must use tcsh for some reason, aliases will solve your immediate problem, but are much weaker than functions.

```
alias helloWorld 'echo "a"'
```

Another possible solution is to invoke a separate script. (You'll have to ensure that the invoked script is in your `$PATH`.)

Answer (score 5):

There are not functions in tcsh. So I see 2 options:

- Use **aliases**:
  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxa500/alias.htm
- Use **goto**. (People tend to criticize go-to, but It actually depends on the context).

There is an other option, use **source** if you want to organize your code with multiple files:

> To run a shell script in your current environment, without creating a
> new process, use the source command. You could run the calculate shell
> script this way: source calculate Should you want to use a shell
> script that updates a variable in the current environment, run it with
> the source command.

src: [OS/390 UNIX System Services tcsh (C Shell) Kit Support Guide - IBM](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjNlbijoKrXAhUEgpAKHS-OB0YQFggtMAE&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.software.ibm.com%2Fs390%2Fzos%2Funix%2Fftp%2Ftcsh.pdf&usg=AOvVaw04WbxxmnHnSB3Pd23Wmjrf)

I think that 'use a different shell' should not be a valid response.

Regards,
Pablo

Comment: Why is "use a different shell" not a valid response? It does solve the problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson The OP specifically asked about C-shell. It is possible that no other shells are available. Or it is a learning exercise (trying something new). It's  also possible the using csh is a requirement (i.e. cannot change it).

Comment: @ScottieH That's all possible. It's also possible that using a different shell is the best solution to the OP's problem. See also [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/167210)

Comment: @KeithThompson I can tell you don't work in tightly controlled environments. :)

Comment: @ScottieH In fact I do work in tightly controlled environments. Of course it's possible that changing shells is not an option. I'm just saying that it's possible that changing shells is the best solution. And even if it's not an option for the OP, knowing that other shells have functions could be useful information for other readers.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code for functions usage in `tcsh`

```
#! /bin/tcsh -f
goto helloWorld
helloWorld:
echo "a"
```

Comment: That's not a function.

Comment: true, not a function, but as noted above somewhat reasonable proxy for one.  Looks like no good options :(

Answer (score 1):

Although the C Shell lacks functions, aliases serve as workaround. However, pipes and I/O redirection don't work well with multi-line aliases, except if `eval` is issued. To avoid `eval`, have the script in a variable and source it from a FIFO:

```
setenv qscr 'if -e $1 then\
echo OK\
else\
echo Not OK\
endif'
mkfifo ~/qscr
alias qscr '( echo "$qscr:q" > ~/qscr & ) ; source ~/qscr'
```

Or have it in an alias alone, with `echo`:

```
alias qscr '( echo '\''if -e $1 then\\
echo OK\\
else\\
echo Not OK\\
endif'\'' > ~/qscr & ) ; source ~/qscr'
mkfifo ~/qscr
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Pablo's answer, I thought of applying `goto` and `source` as one. The result is a recursive script:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

alias function 'set argv = ( _FUNC \!* ) ; source $0'
if ( "$1" == "_FUNC" ) goto "$2"

set ret = "`function myfunc`"
echo "$ret"
exit

myfunc:
function myfunc2
echo "A function."
exit

myfunc2:
echo "Another function."
exit
```

This is much better than aliases in scripts.