# Creating an alias that has foreach and if statements in it

Tags: tcsh

I'm trying to create an alias in my `~/.alias` file as follows. The shell is tcsh.

```
alias getlastlog 'foreach log ( `find dir1/dir2/*log | tac` )\
grep -q "Options.*BRINGUP" $log \
if ( $status == 0 ) then \
continue \
endif \
break \
end \
less $log '
```

Then when I run `getlastlog` in the terminal, I get an error `if: Improper then.`

If I copy paste the following lines in the terminal, it works as expected

```
foreach log ( `find dir1/dir2/*log | tac` )
grep -q "Options.*BRINGUP" $log
if ( $status == 0 ) then
continue
endif
break
end
less $log
```

How I should I create the alias so that it works as expected and I don't get the error `if: Improper then.` ?

Basically, I'm trying to open the latest modified log file using less that does not contain the pattern `Options.*BRINGUP`. This action is performed frequently and hence, I would like to create an alias for it.

Comment: why not instead of `alias` create a function `getlastlog (){ ... }` ?

Comment: I just tried it as follows and added it in my .alias file:
```getlastlog () {
foreach log ( `find dir1/dir2/*log | tac` )
grep -q "Options.*DEBUG" $log
if ( $status == 0 ) then
continue
endif
break
end
less $log
}
```
And I got the error badly placed ()'s

Comment: Okay, I just realized tcsh does not support functions. So, I have to make alias work somehow

Comment: oh man, apparently you are using `tcsh` which [does not support functions..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717020/badly-placed-s-while-declaring-a-function-in-tcsh)

Comment: Yeah, I see everywhere not to use `tcsh`. But I can't move to `bash` so easily because everything and environment and project legacy code and everything etc is in tcsh :(

Comment: My above alias works (as in no syntax errors but not what I want) if I replace `if` statement with something simple like an `echo` command.